# How to add Scroll Pane into tabs

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this simple example of JavaFX tabs

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs Test");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        //Create Tabs
        Tab tabA = new Tab();
        tabA.setText("Main Component");
        //Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();
        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B")); 
        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

        Tab tabB = new Tab();
        tabB.setText("Second Component");
        //Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();
        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));
        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

        Tab tabC = new Tab();
        tabC.setText("Last Component");
        //Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();
        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));
        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

        mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        mainPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        mainPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

How I can add horizontal and vertical scroll Pane into the tab's body. I want to display the scroll pane only when the data is bigger than the visible area. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting contents of tabs to `StackPane`, call `setContent` method with `ScrollPane` object, and set the content of this `ScrollPane` to the corresponding `StackPane`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a basic `javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane` is easy, an example can be found in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html). Here's the code that places a `ScrollPane` in your first `Tab`:

```
        ...
        final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 200, 800, 600);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(rect);
        tabA.setContent(scrollPane);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);
        ...
```

You can find a lot of useful examples in the [JavaFX tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/), too.